# How to use Redis pipeline in Ruby for a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am using the Ruby gem https://github.com/redis/redis-rb.

I want to use pipeline to send several Redis commands in 1 network trip to the Redis server. How can I do this if I have a loop?

For instance, would this work? Or would it simply send all the commands one by one?

```
cache = Redis.new() #blah blah

normalized = cache.pipelined do
        urls.each do |url|
            key= "key:#{url}"    
            cache.get(key)
            key2 = "key2:#{url}"
            cache.get(key2)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrasing "one network trip" is a misunderstanding. All pipelined mode does is send in other commands while waiting on the results of the previous ones. This is in contrast to the default where each request blocks until completed.

If that Ruby library blocks then it will issue them sequentially, and I believe it blocks on anything that requires results. There are asynchronous libraries that do make much better use of the pipelined mode because it's easier to match results to variables in that model. It's also a lot more work.

Normally you use `pipelined` for doing multiple assignments, not retrieval. That way you don't need to wait for the result of an `INCR` to complete before moving to the next one, you can just fire-and-forget.

If you're looking to do quick retrievals, use [`MGET`](https://redis.io/commands/mget).

Comment: Thanks. This is a DOH moment for me. Why oh why did nobody tell me about MGET from the beginning?! Seriously, this exists?!

Comment: The Redis documentation is a lot of fun, and I'd strongly encourage you to look through all the various commands to see the neat tools that are there. It's often pleasantly surprising when you find a neat thing that does exactly what you want.